How to disable WordPress encoding special chars
I have been requested to disable all text encoding on a specific WordPress RSS feed, so a sentence that outputs like this
She said &#8220;oh, you&#8217;re lost&#8221;
would output like this
She said "oh, you're lost"
This is not just about the quotes, but all encoded chars. I'm checking for the feed with is_feed('feed-handle'), and if it is detected, I'm disabling wptexturizer globally with add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' ).
After that, I have the two functions below working on the content and the excerpt.
add_filter( 'the_content_rss', [ $this, 'modify_feed_content' ] );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', [ $this, 'modify_feed_excerpt' ] );

public function modify_feed_content( $content ) {
    $content = wp_specialchars_decode( $content ); // decodes remaining html entities
    return $content;
}

public function modify_feed_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    $excerpt = strip_tags( $excerpt ); // remove html tags
    $excerpt = wp_specialchars_decode( $excerpt ); // decodes remaining html entities
    return $excerpt;
}

I can see it working ok, but I'm still getting some encoded chars, like &#160;, and a few others. I tried chatGPT, but it answered basically with all I have already done.
Any insight on what I'm missing? Any help is very much appreciated.
Thank you all.

Try applying html_entity_decode instead of  wp_specialchars_decode?

That didn't do it, unfortunately. What got me the best results was to add the add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' ) call to the header of the custom rss feed file.

Update:
What got me the best results was to add the add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' ) call to the header of the custom rss feed file.
